# Finding one element of a composite function

Tags: functions

If $f(x) = x - 1$ and $gf(x) = 3 + 2x - \ x^2$, find $g(x)$.

The answer is $4 - \ x^2$ and I can see that this works but I cannot see how it was worked out.

I have started by saying:

let $f(x) = u = x - 1$  and $gf(x) = g(u)$
but can't get any further.

Comment: Hint:  note that $f(x+1)=x$ so $g(x)=g(f(x+1))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=u=x-1$, so $x=u+1$. Then $$g(f(x))=g(u)=3+2x-x^2=$$
$$=3+2(u+1)-(u+1)^2$$
$$=3+2u+2-(u^2+2u+1)$$
$$=5+2u-u^2-2u-1=4-u^2.$$

Thus $g(x)=4-x^2$.

Comment: Easy when you know how! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$g(f(f^{-1}(x))=g(x)=3+2(1-x)-(1-x)^2=4-x^2$

$f^{-1}(x)=1-x$